# Removing element from multidimensional array in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array

I am attempting to remove an element from a multidimensional array in javascript, the array is built like this:

```
selectedClients.push({client: id, package: package_id, transfer: transfer_id});
```

However there can be multiple clients, in multiple packages in multiple transfers in this array, how could I remove an element from this array using all three identifiers rather than just one?

for example:

```
Array[0]
{
client: 1
package: 1
transfer: 1
}
Array[1]
{
client: 2
package: 1
transfer: 1
}
Array[2]
{
client: 1
package: 2
transfer: 2
}
```

Many Thanks

Comment: That's not a multi-D array, thats an array of objects, quite different :)

Comment: take a look at the [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can roll your own function, that will take in an object with the exact amount of properties as the ones in your array, and then `slice` out the object it finds:

Say you pass in:

```
{client: 1, package: 1, transfer: 1}
```

Lets build!

```
//Returns the new array if found, false if nothing
function removeObjectFromArray(objectToRemove, arrayOfObjects) {
    for (var i = 0; i < arrayOfObjects.length; i++) {
        var stringyArrObj       = JSON.stringify(arrayOfObjects[i]),
            stringyRemoveObject = JSON.stringify(objectToRemove);

            if (stringyArrObj === stringyRemoveObject)
                return arrayOfObjects.slice(i, i+1);
    }
return false; 
}
```

Order of the object IS IMPORTANT, as `stringify` wont match up if the objects aren't ordered the same way. If that's an issue, you'll have to write a bit of a larger function comparing the keys individually.